# Laravel eloquent find() having a custom primary key returns not found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have set in my model a custom primary key as:

> ```
> protected $primaryKey = 'id_player';
> ```

It is set as the primary key on MySql

But If I do a

> $rows = DB::table("players")->find($playerId);

It returns no items (but it exists).

**Players Model**

```
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Players extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_player';
 }
```

**PlayersController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Players;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Players;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PlayersController extends Controller{
   ...
   ...
}
```

I'm new on Laravel, what I'm missing?

Comment: I guess you've already tried this, but does: `$rows = DB::table("players")->where('id_player', $playerId)->first();` return the one you are looking for?

Comment: Try using the Eloquent way: $players = Players::find($playerId); This assumes that the model name is Players

Comment: @namelivia, yes I did and it works. But iI would like to try the other option.

Comment: Just a note: Laravel convention is that the model name is singular, so `Player` instead of `Players`. Table name is plural, but since a model represents a single instance (row) in the database, it should be singular (think a single "player")

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis. I need to use the Laravel Convention. Thanks for the noteì.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are querying from the table.

If you want to use Model primaryKey, you need to access from the Model eloquent

*//Supposing your Model Name is User*

```
$row = App\User::find($playerId);
```

Comment: hmm thanks for help can you write what I have to use in my model to work? I'm going to update the post showing you my actual model...

Comment: Yes. Your Model is absolutely right. You only need to use fetch using model `App\Players::find($playerId);` instead of `DB::table("players")->find($playerId);`. The answer should work fine.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something into controller because I'm getting this error: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'players.id' <-- note the "id" primary key instead of my own.

Comment: Could you post your controller? It is working perfectly fine in my local. Might be a problem with the controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fixed!  There was a misunderstanding... too many similar files opened! Everything is working now!  Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
$rows = DB::table("players")->where('id_player', $playerId)->first();
```